# How to change a host value from a different host?

Tags: css, angular

I need to extend an existing component to allow it to remove a margin from the top.

This margin is set within the :host pseudoelement

```
:host {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

I'd like to do add a new class that overwrites this configuration, something like this.

```
:host(.remove-margin-top) {
  :host {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

But when i use the class remove-margin-top, the changes are not being implemented. Any ideas on how can i work around this?

Comment: Do you want the `parentComponent` to change the  CSS `:host` of a `childComponent`?

Comment: @skouch2022 yes, sort of. This is a component in a repository that is being used by multiple applications. 

I want to re use this component from an application, but removing the margin at the top on this specific implementation without affecting the rest of the consumers

Comment: Cool. I added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow `ParentComponent` to change the style of a `ChildComponent`'s host, we can use `@HostBinding` and `@Input` together.

- `@HostBindng` allow us to bind a class to the `ChildComponent`.
- `@Input` allow us to the supply a boolean value to turn on/off the class.

To avoid affecting the rest of the consumers, we will set a default value for the `hasMarginTop` to `true`. This way, the existing consumers doesn't need to update their code. The new one can use `hasMarginTop` and set it to true if it doesn't need to have the margin-top.

##### child.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @HostBinding('class.has-margin-top')
  @Input()
  public hasMarginTop = true; 

}
```

##### child.component.css

```css
:host {
  display: block;
}

// this only apply when hasMarginTop is true.
:host.has-margin-top {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

##### parent.component.html

```html
...
<!-- remove margin -->
<app-child hasMarginTop="false"></app-child>


<!-- default has margin -->
<app-child></app-child>
...
```